# Set the width property for textinput

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

I have created a widget in the same fashion as the showcase application. However I do not see anything in the api [documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html) to limit the width of the input field. How can I set the width?

```
CTextInput:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '32dp'
    multiline: False
    hint_text: 'SNMP Community String(s)'
```

Answer (score 8):

By `width` I'm assuming you mean text length, as setting the `width` of a widget is just as easy as setting the `height` is.

There is an [example of text filtering](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#filtering) in the documentation you linked which could easily be modified to limit the length:

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        # limit to 5 chars
        substring = substring[:5 - len(self.text)]
        return super(MyTextInput, self).insert_text(substring, from_undo=from_undo)
```

If you happen to be running the development version of Kivy (1.8.1-dev, from git), this is even easier and can be done from kv. You can limit the length of the text with a callable [`input_filter`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.input_filter). Here's a quick example:

```
TextInput:
    # limit to 5 chars
    input_filter: lambda text, from_undo: text[:5 - len(self.text)]
```